# PHP - Whatsapp Web - Message format

Tags: php, encoding, whatsapp, urlencode

How to format **Whatsapp Web Message** ?
I trying replacing tags like this :

```
$nl         = "%0D%0A";
$space      = "%20";
$MSG        =  nl2br($MSG);
$MSG        =  str_replace( array("<b>","<bold>","</b>","</bold>"), array("*","*","*","*"), $MSG);
$MSG        =  str_replace( array(" ","<br>","\n", "\r\n"), array($space,$nl,$nl,$nl), $MSG);
```

I tried using **urlencode**, **htmlspecialchars** and nothing.

I´m receiving on **https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXX&text=MSG** a totally unformated and with a lot of chars string. Like this :

```
%F0%9F%94%94%2A...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error and I´m posting here to help others.

```
// Should use UTF8
$MSG        =  utf8_encode($MSG);

// Whatsapp patterns
$nl         = "%0D%0A"; // newline
$space      = "%20";    // space

// Replace some Whatstapp tags 
$MSG        =  str_replace( array("<b>","<bold>","</b>","</bold>"), array("*","*","*","*"), $MSG);

// Replace newline to Whatsapp format
$MSG        =  str_replace( array(" ","<br>","\n", "\r\n"), array($space,$nl,$nl,$nl), $MSG);
```

I replace only *BOLD* but you can add others tags. See :
https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-format-your-messages/?lang=en